# What is an alternative method to replace grayscale value?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, grayscale, 2048

I am trying to make a bot to read the data from the game, 2048, and decide the best movement. I have preset the grayscale value for every number. But unfortunately, the grayscale value for an empty slot and the number 512 is the same. Are there any easy alternatives to solve this issue?

[The screenshot of the number 512](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8TCJ.png)

[The screenshot of the empty slot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8GIw.png)

This is the relevant code :

```
class Values:
    empty = 195
    two = 230
    four = 225
    eight = 190
    sixteen = 172
    threeTwo = 154
    sixFour = 136
    oneTwoEight = 204
    twoFiveSix = 200
    fiveOneTwo = 195
    oneZeroTwoFour = 193
    twoZeroFourEight = 189

valueArray = [empty, two, four, eight,
              sixteen, threeTwo, sixFour,
              oneTwoEight, twoFiveSix, fiveOneTwo,
              oneZeroTwoFour, twoZeroFourEight]

screenImage = ImageGrab.grab()
grayScreenImage = ImageOps.grayscale(screenImage)
for index, cord in enumerate(Coordinates.coordinateArray):
    pixel = grayScreenImage.getpixel(cord)
    try:
        position = Values.valueArray.index(pixel)
        
    except:
        position = 0

    if position == 0:
        currentGrid[index] = 0
    else:
        currentGrid[index] = 2 ** position
```

Comment: maybe you should count white pixels. Empty slot should give zero.

Comment: or maybe you should get pixel before converting to grayscale and compare it with RGB value.